Running powershell commands inside a python script as a cli tool to target an azure vm generates a permission error
I am trying to create a CLI tool using python that lists all subscriptions in an azure account. The user then needs to enter the number of the subscription that they which to consult. After that, all VMs in that subscription are listed. The user then enters the option number of the VM where they want the log shipper (winlogbeat) to be installed. The script then should download and install a dn run winlogbeat as a service inside that VM. I am using managed identity.
The problem I am facing have something to do with permissions to access certain paths in that VM, although I am using the option -Verb runAs in my subprocess.run as follows:
subprocess.run(['powershell', '-Command', f'Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command \"{powershell_command}\"" -Verb runAs'], check=True)

Here's my code :
def run_command_as_admin(command):
    subprocess.run(['powershell', '-Command', f'Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command \\"{command}\\"" -Verb runAs'])

def install_winlogbeat_service(vm_name):
    try:
        download_winlogbeat()
        
        run_command_as_admin(f'& "C:\\Program Files\\Winlogbeat\\install-service-winlogbeat.ps1"')
        click.echo(f"Winlogbeat installed and service started on VM '{vm_name}'")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        click.echo(f"Error: Failed to install Winlogbeat and start service on VM '{vm_name}': {e}")

def download_winlogbeat():
    winlogbeat_version = "7.16.3"  # Example version
    winlogbeat_url = f"https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/winlogbeat/winlogbeat-{winlogbeat_version}-windows-x86_64.zip"
    
    download_dir = os.path.expanduser("~")  # User's home directory
    zip_file_path = os.path.join(download_dir, "winlogbeat.zip")

    subprocess.run(['powershell', '-Command', f'Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "{winlogbeat_url}" -OutFile "{zip_file_path}"'], check=True)
    
    subprocess.run(['powershell', '-Command', f'Expand-Archive -Path "{zip_file_path}" -DestinationPath "C:\\Program Files" -Force'], check=True)

    os.rename(os.path.join("C:\\Program Files", f"winlogbeat-{winlogbeat_version}-windows-x86_64"), "C:\\Program Files\\Winlogbeat")

and here's the error I am getting:
New-Item : Access to the path 'powershell' is denied.
At C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:986 char:21
+ ...New-Item $currentArchiveEntryPath -Type Directory -Confir ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo: PermissionDenied: (C:\Program File...ule\powershell:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

and same for :
New-Item : Access to the path 'visualization' is denied.
New-Item : Access to the path 'security' is denied. 
New-Item : Access to the path 'config' is denied.
New-Item : Access to the path 'sysmon' is denied.


Please confirm how you are logged into the VM (as a user, service principal, or identity), and ensure that the Azure Virtual Machine Administration role is assigned. This role may be required to access the system32 path in the VM.

Hey venkat , thank you for your comment . I used azure managed identity by using this python module :
def get_credentials():
return DefaultAzureCredential()

Have you assigned the Virtual Machine Administrator Login role to managed identity? If not, assign the same role and check it.

I hope this helps you to resolve the issue?

New-Item : Access to the path 'powershell' is denied

If you encounter an error while attempting to create a directory under C:\WINDOWS\system32\ on the VM, you may require Local Admin access. Since you are connecting using managed identity to that VM, please check the MS Doc for more details.

To resolve the issue , you may assign Virtual Machine Administrator Login role to the Managed Identity.
VM-create a Directory using invoke cmd.ps1
New-Item -Path "C:\Windows\System32" -Name "Powershell-Test1" -ItemType "directory"

Here is the script I used to create a directory inside an Azure VM.
Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId "9b0d59a2-6329-4ba8-8d20-b32174689edc"
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName 'Venkat' -VMName 'venkat-vm' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'VM-create a Directory using invoke cmd.ps1'

Output:

After running the script, the folder has been created successfully.

